# When does load, store, and alloca get used in LLVM

Tags: c, llvm

I am looking at LLVM to see how they use `load`, `store`, and `alloca`. In the first slide below, there is no use of them. In the second, there is use of `alloca`.

I am not familiar with C so going to have to bring myself up to speed in order to run an example and figure this out myself, but wanted to ask if anyone knew already. Not sure the kind of example C code to write in order to determine the output that uses `load`, `store`, and `alloca` in LLVM.

The question is, when LLVM uses `load`, `store`, and `alloca`.

Wondering if load/store are necessary as well, or LLVM can do without it.

Figure 1 ↓

[image]

Figure 2 ↓

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without optimizations, clang will produce LLVM code where there's one `alloca` for each local variable, one `read` for each use of that variable as an r-value and one `store` for each assignment to that variable (including its initialization).

With optimizations, clang will try to minimize the number of `read`s and `store` and will often eliminate the `alloca` completely if possible (using only registers).

One way to ensure that the variable is stored in memory, even with optimizations, would be to take its address (since registers don't have an address).

> Wondering if load/store are necessary as well, or LLVM can do without it.

You need `store` / `load` whenever you write to memory locations. So the question becomes whether you can do without memory, storing everything in registers. Since LLVM (unlike real machines) supports an infinite amount of registers, that's a valid question.

However, as I mentioned, registers don't have addresses. So any code that takes the address of a variable, needs to use memory. So does any code that performs arithmetic on addresses, such as code that indexes arrays.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Very clear.

Answer (score 4):

`alloca` allocates memory in the function's local frame. It is necessary to create a variable whose address is taken, like in this example:

```
void foo(int* ptr) {
    *ptr = 4;
}

int main() {
    int value = 0;
    foo(&value);
    printf("%i\n", value); // 4
}
```

If it doesn't inline `foo`, then LLVM will need an `alloca` instruction in `main` to create the memory that backs the `value` variable. `foo` needs to use `store` to put 4 at the address that `ptr` points to, and `main` then needs to use `load` to load the contents of `value` after it's been modified by `foo`.

Compilers for C-family languages typically prefer to start off using `alloca` for every variable in the function's frame, and then let LLVM optimize the `alloca`s into SSA values. In many cases, the compiler is able to promote `alloca`ted variables to SSA values, as the `ssa2` function shows. The SSA form is capable of representing variables that meet the following two conditions:

- their addresses aren't taken
- their size is fixed

"Taking the address" of a variable is an operation that doesn't exist in Javascript/Ruby, so you may need to get up to speed on C to understand what it means. It is extremely common in C and C++.

"Fixed size" means that the compiler knows ahead of time how much memory it needs for a specific data structure. It always knows for simple integers, for instance, but arrays often have a variable size. Arrays of a size that isn't known at runtime can be allocated with `alloca` or `malloc`, and then you need to access their contents with `load` and `store`.

Finally, note that your second example is broken: it reads from an uninitialized value, and if you compile it at higher optimization levels, you'll just get `ret i32 undef`.